# using a watcher to dynamically change form data

Tags: vue.js

OK, so I am tired and I know something I am doing is wrong (more than it doesn't work LOL) but I cannot see it. So, this is the situation.
I have 3 fields a user fills in

- Day
- Month
- Year

That needs to then be combined into a formal date that is in Y-m-d format and stored inside form.birthdate

I THOUGHT using a Vue Watcher would be the solution but... when someone fills out the form, it doesnt seem to update the form.birthdate which then causes an error of "birthdate not found" - HOWEVER, if I change watch to computed on dev, in Vue DevTools, if I open it up, it instantly populates the data.

What am I missing that should be updating the specific form data object/string while the user types.

```
    watch: {
        getBirthdate: function () {
            let birthdate = `${this.birthdate.year}-${this.birthdate.month}-${this.birthdate.day}`;
            this.form.birthdate = birthdate;
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

As `v-model` is a `two-way` binding which means if you change the input value, the bound data will be changed. Hence, Values will automatically get updated but as you want to combine those `day`, `month` and `year` without any explicit method call, you can achieve that by using computed property.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    birthdate: {
      day: '',
      month: '',
      year: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    combinedBirthDate: function() {
      let birthDate = `${this.birthdate.year}-${this.birthdate.month}-${this.birthdate.day}`;
      return birthDate;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form>
    <label>Day</label>
    <input type="text" name="day" v-model="birthdate.day"><br>
    <label>Month</label>
    <input type="text" name="month" required v-model="birthdate.month"><br>
    <label>Year</label>
    <input type="text" name="year" v-model="birthdate.year">
  </form>
  <pre>{{ birthdate }}</pre>
  <pre>{{ combinedBirthDate }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So what you suggested by computed is where I started and after speaking to the Vue Discord someone said use a watch which hey, makes sense I guess. But, the issue with using computed is it doesnt seem to update this.form.birthdate UNLESS I have Vue Devtools open and I watch it update the form realtime. so in production its broken.